# Locating late 19th century British immigration/landing records?

Tags: england, immigration, 1890s, 1880s

Many of my ancestors came to Britain around 1880-1900. They were originally from Russia but that may not have been their point of departure by sea.

Are there immigration or landing records for this period and, if so, how can they be searched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ancestry](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1518) has some incoming passenger lists, but warns that pre-1890 arrivals may not have survived. Also note: the UK kept no passenger lists for journeys from Europe or the Mediterranean, the only exception being people who joined "listable" ships in Europe or the Mediterranean - eg joining a ship from India to London at Naples.

You could also look at the [UK Aliens Entry Books](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1609) and the [UK Naturalisation Certificates](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=9156) also at Ancestry.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning what the Ancestry link says: the UK kept no passenger lists for journeys from Europe or the Mediterranean, the only exception being people who joined "listable" ships in Europe or the Mediterranean - eg joining a ship from India to London at Naples. That was probably only done to make life easier by having only one type of passenger on board.

Comment: @AdrianB38 I'll edit it in -- thanks.